# Docker server - cannot connect to realm

Tags: azerothcore

I've just deployed the azerothcore stack using docker compose, great guide by the way!
Everything's working great, inside my network I can auth ok, but when I am presented with the realm list in the client I cannot choose AzerothCore, it attempts to connect then presents me with the realm list again. No additional error!

Is this just my firewall (i've allowed ports 8085 and 3724!) or could I have missed something else?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED - after updating my row on the realmlist db table to change the server's ip info from local loopback to the host's local IP I restarted the stack and this is working great now!